# html center align

Tags: html, alignment, center

How can i make text center but the first letter start at the same place?

from this

```
                                  text 1
                                text text
                             text 2 text text
```

to this

```
                             text 1
                             text text
                             text 2 text text
```

Comment: You could center the parent div using css. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: it's the result from this         echo'
            <tr id="to">
            <td><div style="text-align: center;"><a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a></td></center>
            </tr></table>
           ';

Comment: this will flush many url but the result will like the no first 1 above, how to make them like the second 1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
   .center{
      margin: auto auto;
      width: 250px;
   }
</style>


<div class="center">
       Multiline text
       ight here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So u should not use align center. but instead of one div containing your text , you shoud have 2 or 3 divs(that would be like columns), your text would be displayed normally inside, aligned left, like u want